# return value from objc protocol in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

i have an @objc optional function circleMenu()

```
@objc public protocol CircleMenuDelegate {
    @objc optional func circleMenu(_ circleMenu: CircleMenu, willDisplay button: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
}
```

i would like to call this from another class and get the atIndex value.  this is what I've been trying:

```
class AppMainViewController: UIViewController, CircleMenuDelegate  {
    func circleMenu(_ circleMenu: CircleMenu, willDisplay button: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
        print(atIndex)
    }
```

however it just doesn't return any value

Comment: trying to call it from a button like:     @IBAction func getValueButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        circleMenu(CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
    } returns error "can not convert value "CircleMenu..Type" to expected argument type 'CircleMenu'

Comment: The key bit there is "It just doesn't return any value." You can't get a function that doesn't return a value to return a value, regarless of whether it's defined as `@objc` or not. You need to redefine the function in the protocol if you want it to return a value.

Comment: it seems to return a value in the circlemenu class, delegate?.circleMenu?(self, willDisplay: sender, atIndex: sender.tag).  however i am unable to get this value from in another class.... trying to call the function from another class with: circleMenu(CircleMenu, willDisplay: UIButton, atIndex: Int) returns error: "can not convert value "CircleMenu..Type" to expected argument type 'CircleMenu

Comment: You need to set your `AppMainViewController` instance as the delegate on an instance of `CircleMenu` and then it will call the function when appropriate. You can't just abitrarily call the function.

Comment: im not sure how to do that as the circle menu is subclass of UIButton so it isn't like i can go 'self.delegate........'

Comment: Not `self.delegate` but `circleMenu.delegate = self`

Comment: unfortunately circlemenu.delegate doesn't exist